# Unable to add LI item inside DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using subway map jquery plugin called [jquery.subwayMap-0.5.0.js](http://kalyani.com/2010/10/subway-map-visualization-jquery-plugin/).What I am trying to do is to add li inside div. I tried this code `$(".subway-map #map2").append('<li data-coords="10,6">NorthEast</li>');`but it is not working. If I change the div class from **subway-map** to **subway-map2** then the li will be added inside the div.Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>Subway Map</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.subwayMap-0.5.0.js"></script>
            <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                font-family: Verdana;
                font-size: 8pt;
            }

            /* The main DIV for the map */
            .subway-map
            {
                margin: 0;
                width: 500px;
                height:410px;
                background-color: white;
            }

            /* Text labels */
            .text
            {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
            }

            #legend
            {
                float: left;
                width: 250px;
                height:400px;
            }

            #legend div
            {
                height: 25px;
            }

            #legend span
            {
                margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
            }
            .subway-map span
            {
                margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
            }

            </style>
        </head>
        <body>

            <div class="subway-map" data-columns="12" data-rows="10" data-cellSize="40" data-legendId="legend" data-textClass="text" data-gridNumbers="true" data-grid="true" data-lineWidth="8">

                <ul id="map" data-color="#ff4db2" data-label="jQuery Widgets">          
                    <li data-coords="2,2"><a href="#">North</a></li>
                    <li data-coords="4,2"><a href="#">South</a></li>
                    <li data-coords="6,2"><a href="#">West</a></li>
                </ul>

                 <ul id="map2" data-label="jQuery Interactions" data-shiftCoords="0,-1">          
                    <li data-coords="8,2"><a href="#">West</a></li>
                    <li data-coords="10,4"><a href="#">East</a></li>

                </ul>

             </div>    

            <div id="legend"></div>


            <script type="text/javascript">

                $(".subway-map").subwayMap({ debug: true });

               $(".subway-map #map2").append('<li data-coords="10,6">NorthEast</li>');


            </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: A basic form of your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ow8eg63x/. Check the console to be sure theres no errors caused by other sections of your JS code

Comment: The only allowed direct parent elements for `li` are `ol` and `ul`. Everything else is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `subwayMap` plugin will override all the DOM in the specified container.

Make a copy(`.clone`) of the `parent-container` and do `.append` in the `cloned-copy` and re-initialize the `subwayMap` over `cloned` copy and `.append` it in the `DOM`

```js
var clonned = $('.subway-map').clone(true);
$(".subway-map").subwayMap({
  debug: true
});
clonned.find("#map2").append('<li data-coords="10,6">NorthEast</li>');
clonned.subwayMap({
  debug: true
});
$('body').html(clonned);
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ow8eg63x/3/)